# Set base directory jade, grunt, compass on external files

Tags: gruntjs, pug, compass

I am using jade grunt and compass to produce a site, and instead of havving to type the correct path to files within jade file e.g.:

```
link(href='../../../../stylesheets/sections/pdp.css'
```

I was wondering i there was a way of using something like /stylesheets/sections.pdp.css

so I don't have to write the correct path each time.

Thanks!

EDIT:

**config.rb**

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "assets/images"
javascripts_dir = "scripts"
#output_style = :compressed
relative_assets=true
line_comments = false
```

Comment: Can you not have compass output the pdp.css closer to the root jade index file?

Comment: @MikeMellor how exactly? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using grunt for compass? Either way could you post your compass grunt config or your compass config.rb?

Comment: well without knowing your structure it's a bit hard, bit where you have css_dir you could add a path to make it sit next to your index html. So i'll make up a structure for now - css_dir = "www/mysite/jade/stylesheets" then if your index was sat in the same folder you could just use link(href='stylesheets/sections/pdp.css'

Answer (score 1):

In your example, pug is not reading the file at `../../../../stylesheets/sections/pdp.css`. It is outputting that string as the value for the `href` attribute of the `link` HTML tag, like this:

```
<link href="../../../../stylesheets/sections/pdp.css" />
```

So these paths are not relative to your `views` directory: they are relative to the path that the browser is getting.

You may benefit from using absolute URLs for these`href` fields, instead of relative URLs. Like this:

```
link(href='/stylesheets/sections/pdp.css')
```

The code below is equivalent, but factors out the path to the css directory, which might be useful for other tags:

```
- var cssDir = '/stylesheets';
link(href= cssDir + '/sections/pdp.css')
```